# Uniform set method not working

Tags: java, collections

So i am writing a program where i want it to set all the elements in a vector to a specified value and specified NEW vector length. This is my code so far:

```
public static Vector uniform(int length, long value) {

    Vector vector = new Vector(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
        vector.elements[i] = this.value;
    }
    return this.vector;
}
```

However, when this program runs, all the numbers in the vector are set to the specified value however it does not change the number of integers in the array itself. How can i fix my code to show this?

Comment: `vector.elements[i]` shouldn't even compile since there is no `elements` property, not even a protected/private one. I guess you mean `vector.add(value)` instead (note that `new Vector(length)` will create a vector with an initial _capacity_ of  `length` - it will still be empty after construction). Besides that `Vector` is quite outdated, why not use `ArrayList` instead?

Comment: You should avoid naming you class the same as a common builtin type. `Vector` is a built in class.  As you have your own there is no way to know what you need to fix.

Comment: `uniform` creates an other, new Vector - might that be the misunderstanding? Another remark: better use long i.o. Long, maybe with a `boolean calculated;`. Long is much slower because of the need for boxing/unboxing to long, and a possible null check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the uniform code, you need to construct a new `Vector vector`, and then write a loop which goes through every single elements of the `vector`, and then assign each element with the specified value in the constructor. Once this is done, then return the vector that is produced, as so:

```
 Vector vector = new Vector(length);

 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   vector.elements[i] = value;
 }

 return vector;
```